# How a Tkinter application can run on 2 monitors?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a Tkinter application, with multiple Toplevel (and OptionMenu).

It works perfectly fine when I only use 1 screen.
But when I move a Toplevel in a different screen (from where the Tk root stands), the OptionMenu in it does not work anymore. If I move the Tk root on the new screen, the OptionMenu works again.

Does anyone know why? And more importantly, does anyone know how I could make my application work on 2 screens simultaneously?

Thank you very much,

Tristan

--- EDITION 04/13 ---

This is a basic code to understand what happens:

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_optionmenu(master):
    toplevel = tk.Toplevel(master)
    choices = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    var_choice = tk.StringVar(toplevel, value='A')
    tk.Label(toplevel, text='Essai: ').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=(5,2), pady=2)
    tk.OptionMenu(toplevel, var_choice, *choices).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w', padx=(0,10), pady=(0,10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    create_optionmenu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

And 3 screenshots: 
(1) root and toplevel in the same screen 1: it works 
(2) root on screen 1 and toplevel on screen 2: it does not work 
(3) root and toplevel on screen 2: it works
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot?

Comment: Could You also please include python code related to this issue (about menu to be specific but You can also provide a bit more)

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post. Thank you very much!

Comment: Works fine for me. Tried on my 4 screens, 2 of them are connected through a docking station. Windows 10, your issue might be Mac.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue but if I connect the second screen after starting the GUI, and move the toplevel to this screen then the menu appears on the wrong screen (no matter where the root is). Have you tried to use a `tk.Menubutton` with a `tk.Menu` instead (making sure that both have your toplevel as master)?

Comment: @BoobyTrap: Thank you. Does anyone know why this problem happen with Mac?

Comment: @j_4321: Thanks. So I tried with Menubutton and Menu, but I have exactly the same problem... (it only works when the toplevel is on the same screen as the root)